# "Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException"

Tags: 9, debugging, plugins

I get this exception, which does not say which plugin causes it.

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException
> The "" entity type does not exist. at /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php line 139

How can I debug this error?

Comment: Not to sound glib, but…use a debugger?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2980110 and there is the same reported on some contributed modules. We can’t answer this question absent more information except to say “use a debugger”.

Comment: Post the message you get when you enable all messages, with backtrace information (/admin/config/development/logging). Where and when do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I add this code in the file Entity/EntityTypeManager.php before the line 139 and I get all the error information that I don't get with Watchdog

```
$e = new \Exception;
var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
exit;
```